# how to enable textbox when radiobuttonlist is selected yes in asp.net using jquery without using autopostback=true

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoBtnHasNotified" runat="server" 
  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RdoBtnHasNotified_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList></td>

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtHowNotified" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#<%= RdoBtnHasNotified.ClientID =%>').click() {
   if ($(this).find('input:checked').val()) == 'Yes' {
      $('#idOfYourTextBox').attr('enabled','true');
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server" onclick="Toggle()">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 function Toggle()
 {
     var radio = document.getElementsByName('<%=rbl.ClientID %>');
     var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>');
        for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++)
        {
           if (radio[j].checked)
           {
                if(radio[j].value == '1')
                {
                    txt.style.display = '';
                }
                else
                {
                   txt.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: why you took for loop instead you can simply do it by if conditions only??